Unwanted line extension after tcolorbox in longtable
I am using tcolorboxes inside the longtable environment. This worked well, but with a recent (or maybe not so recent) change in one of the packages, an extension to the lontable-line after a tcolorbox is produced (but not so after normal text), see picture:

noexpandafter in the tcolorbox environment removed the unwanted line-extension, but in the end, I would like to have a small after skip value like 4pt and as soon as this is introdcued, the line extension is back.
Similarly, \LTpost did not help with the line extension.
Here is a minimal working example. Thanks for feedback.
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{formula}{\centering\tcolorbox[
    colback = black!10!white,
    colframe = white,
    halign = center,
    valign = center,
    width=(\linewidth),%
    box align=center,
    nobeforeafter,
    before = \par,
    before skip = 0pt,
    after = \par,
    after skip = 0pt,
]}{\endtcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.225\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}}
    something & 
    \begin{formula}
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        $a$ & $=$ & $b$ \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{formula} 
    some text \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.225\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}}
    something & 
    \begin{formula}
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        $a$ & $=$ & $b$ \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{formula} \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}


ending a p column in vertical mode is tricky. You can remove the final strut:

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\def\eatfinalstrut{\ifvmode\let\@finalstrut\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{formula}{\centering\tcolorbox[
    colback = black!10!white,
    colframe = white,
    halign = center,
    valign = center,
    width=(\linewidth),%
    box align=center,
    nobeforeafter,
    before = \par,
    before skip = 0pt,
    after = \par,
    after skip = 0pt,
]}{\endtcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.225\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}}
    something & 
    \begin{formula}
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        $a$ & $=$ & $b$ \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{formula} 
    some text \\
\end{longtable}


\begin{longtable}{p{0.225\textwidth}|p{0.7\textwidth}<\eatfinalstrut}
    something & 
   \begin{formula}
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        $a$ & $=$ & $b$ \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{formula} \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}


thanks , this works perfectly!
